# Anyone knows how to make this type of name saving when the game is complete?

Tags: android

Can anyone give me a sample on how to do this type of name saving when the game was completed.
Thanks in advance. I will appreciate your response.

[image: Saving Name when the game was completed]

Comment: Dialog examples - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html Storage Examples - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: did you using any game platform ?

Comment: i used eclipse, ahm, that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple dialog, with some text and an input field ([EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html)). You can create something like this extending the [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) class (using the Android SDK). To save/store your data, you can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).